# Dynamic Dependency Injection at The Run Time

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, dynamic-programming

i have the following classes

```cs
public class GetTestByIdQuery : ICqrsQuery<JustTestDto>
{
    public Guid JustTestId { get; set; }

    public GetTestByIdQuery(Guid justTestId)
    {
    JustTestId = justTestId;
    }
}
```

and

```cs
public class ListTestsQuery : ICqrsQuery<List<JustTestDto>>
{
}
```

how can i register them dynamically at the run time using reflection by getting all the classes that implements the interfaces `ICqrsQuery` and `ICqrsQuery<T>` ?

i already wrote the following code

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddCqrsQueries(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    var queries = assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract &&
                    t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType &&
                    i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICqrsQuery<>)));

    foreach (var query in queries)
    {
        var interfaces = query.GetInterfaces();
        foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
        {
            if (@interface.IsGenericType
                && @interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICqrsQuery<>))
            {
                var constructor = query.GetConstructors().FirstOrDefault();
                var constParameters = constructor?.GetParameters() ?? null;
                var parameterValues =
                    constParameters != null ? new object[constParameters.Length] : null;

                if (parameterValues?.Length > 0 && parameterValues != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < constParameters.Length; i++)
                    {
                        parameterValues[i] = services.BuildServiceProvider()
                            .GetService(constParameters[i].ParameterType);
                    }

                    services.AddTransient(serviceProvider =>
                    {
                        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(query, parameterValues);
                        return instance;
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    ///no parameters
                    services.AddTransient(query);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return services;
}
```

it works fine with the classes that has no parameters such as `ListTestsQuery` but for classes with constructor parameters it doesn't such as `GetTestByIdQuery`

i have notice that the problem is with `var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(query, parameterValues);` since its return type is `object?` although at run time its evaluated to `GetTestByIdQuery`, if i do explicit casting to type `GetTestByIdQuery` it works otherwise it doesn't

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to register them anyway? It seems to me that `GetTestByIdQuery` and `ListTestsQuery` are your query *messages*. You rather want to register their *handlers*. Don't you have a companion `ICqrsQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>` interface? It's unclear what it is you are trying to achieve here. You might be over-complicating things.

Comment: by implementing the mentioned interfaces its guaranteed that all the team are registering the MediatR interfaces, and their commands and queries are registered for dependency injections

Comment: I believe you misunderstand how both MediatR and DI are supposed to work. You are not expected to register your runtime data (message) objects in the DI Container. Solely the handlers (the behavior) is expected to be registered and registering them should be rather straightforward, considering that MediatR contains helper methods (e.g. `RegisterServicesFromAssembly`) for that. Or perhaps I misunderstand from your question what it is you are trying to accomplish and why. If so, please elaborate.

Comment: assume i have an API to create user, for this API i need to use ` _mediator.Send(createUserCommand)` to send it to `createUserCommandHandler`, now what i need is to inject `createUserCommand` in `UserController` same thing if i had a query or other commands

Comment: What does that mean, to "inject the createUserCommand in the UserController?" If you are referring to the DI terminology "injecting" (as in: injecting a dependency in the constructor), this is not a good idea. The command is not a DI dependency with behavior, it is a data object containing runtime data. You don't inject a command because it contains runtime data. But perhaps you are referring to the concept of model binding where you supply the command to a controller's action method, where the data comes from a web request. But that doesn't require a command t o be registered with DI.

Comment: yes im referring to  model binding where i supply the command to a controller's action method and give the command the the data from the action method

Comment: Like I mentioned in my previous command, you don't have to register your messages in the DI container to accomplish model binding. Those are two completely separate mechanisms. I would even expect that your message types will be model bound automatically without any configuration, although your custom constructor might cause trouble. But this can be solved using a custom model binder implementation; registering message types in the DI Container will not help you.